# Python 2.7 - adding custom objects to a list then printing out the attribute prints random value

Tags: python, list

I have this custom object:

```
class Neuron(object):
    def __init__(self):
            self.bias = 1.0
        self.weightBias = uniform(-1, 1)
        # self.weightBias = 1000
        self.area = 0.0
        self.weightArea = uniform(-1, 1)
        # self.weightArea = 1000
        self.perimeter = 0.0
        self.weightPerimeter = uniform(-1, 1)
        # self.weightPerimeter = 1000
        self.compactness = 0.0
        self.weightCompactness = uniform(-1, 1)
        # self.weightCompactness = 1000
        self.length = 0.0
        self.weightLength = uniform(-1, 1)
        # self.weightLength = 1000
        self.width = 0.0
        self.weightWidth = uniform(-1, 1)
        # self.weightWidth = 1000
        self.asymmetryCoefficient = 0.0
        self.weightAsymmetryCoefficient = uniform(-1, 1)
        # self.weightAsymmetryCoefficient = 1000
        self.lengthGroove = 0.0
        self.weightLengthGroove = uniform(-1, 1)
        # self.weightLengthGroove = 1000
        self.activationValue = 0.0
        self.output = 0
```

I have a conditional, and inside this I add an instance of my Neuron class to a list called `errorNeuron1`:

```
# Calculates the output, 0 or 1, for the neuron
def calculateOutput(neuron):
    activationValue = neuron.bias * neuron.weightBias
    activationValue += neuron.area * neuron.weightArea
    activationValue += neuron.perimeter * neuron.weightPerimeter
    activationValue += neuron.compactness * neuron.weightCompactness
    activationValue += neuron.length * neuron.weightLength
    activationValue += neuron.width * neuron.weightWidth
    activationValue += neuron.asymmetryCoefficient * neuron.weightAsymmetryCoefficient
    activationValue += neuron.lengthGroove * neuron.weightLengthGroove

    neuron.activationValue = activationValue
    neuron.output = 1 if activationValue >= 0 else 0
    return neuron


# Retrieves data from row
def parseRow(neuron, row):
    neuron.area = float(row[1][0])
    neuron.perimeter = float(row[1][1])
    neuron.compactness = float(row[1][2])
    neuron.length = float(row[1][3])
    neuron.width = float(row[1][4])
    neuron.asymmetryCoefficient = float(row[1][5])
    neuron.lengthGroove = float(row[1][6])

    return neuron

def main():
    df = importCSV('trainSeeds.csv')

    neuron1 = Neuron()
    neuron2 = Neuron()

    errorNeuron1 = []
    errorNeuron2 = []
    for i in range(0, 1):
        # Iterate over dataframe rows
        for row in df.iterrows():
            neuron1 = parseRow(neuron1, row)
            # print(neuron1.area)
            neuron1 = calculateOutput(neuron1)

            expectedOutput = row[1][7]

            neuron2 = parseRow(neuron2, row)
            neuron2 = calculateOutput(neuron2)

            expectedOutputBinary = format(int(expectedOutput), '02b')

            # If the expectedOutput is equal to the output of the first node
            if int(expectedOutputBinary[0]) != neuron1.output:
                print(neuron1.activationValue)
                errorNeuron1.append((neuron1.activationValue, row))

                # neuron1 = calculateNewWeights(neuron1.output, neuron1, int(expectedOutputBinary[0]))
            elif int(expectedOutputBinary[1]) != neuron2.output:
                errorNeuron2.append(neuron2)
                # neuron2 = calculateNewWeights(neuron1.output, neuron2, int(expectedOutputBinary[1]))

        # errorNeuron1.sort(key=lambda x: x.activationValue)

        print("----------------------------------------")

        for n in errorNeuron1:
            print n
```

How can I add a custom object to a list, and then print each value without getting garbage duplicate values? Also, what exactly is going on in this scenario?

Here is the output when I print before I add to `errorNeuron`:

> 1.37930801491
>   1.3248274347
>   1.38542318785
>   1.39868417375
>   1.32901788598
>   1.38486475771
>   1.42985927348
>   1.41234073472
>   1.39305049211
>   1.36992907231
>   1.44747542914
>   1.3691793289
>   1.44158908789
>   1.4216161728
>   1.40943076719
>   1.41935402214
>   1.47371279276
>   1.33364482064
>   1.32809690259
>   1.46776554321
>   1.42706344947
>   1.41345102369
>   1.30522785708
>   1.38857331887
>   1.35931718327
>   1.31726730896
>   1.43862228814
>   1.41687773781
>   1.4188485406
>   1.45373663027
>   1.36475688453
>   1.41244050385
>   1.47747389879
>   1.39913433929
>   1.39572965064
>   1.37398585466
>   1.39037534707
>   1.38703336165
>   1.43049919876
>   1.53328689772
>   1.42474806554
>   1.41506511897
>   1.40265486573
>   1.49820537833
>   1.42285883588
>   1.36153921531
>   1.34902938453
>   1.40761425156
>   1.39036430332
>   1.38797706537
>   1.45461203476
>   1.47017316218
>   1.45939109969
>   1.43000636609
>   1.38050268146

Here is the output when I loop through each item in `errorNeuron1`

> 1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648
>   1.50138570648

Comment: You *need* to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how is this not minimal, complete or verifiable? What else can I add to make it so.

Comment: @Michael The data being used that's leading to the incorrect result. Also, what output you expect for the given input.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I added the output

Comment: Show the full code as a [MCVE]. It's not clear how data is being generated, or completely how the neuron list is populated. It looks though like you're altering the same neuron and adding the one neuron to the list multiple times instead of creating multiple neurons.

Comment: @Carcigenicate updated

Comment: You only ever create one (or rather two) neurons outside of the loop, then just overwrite the same neuron over and over again. `parseRow` should return a new neuron, not overwrite the one passed in. Why are you passing one in just to overwrite it?

Comment: Again, you need to provide a [mcve] please read that link